# Draw function not working with parameter

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Whenever I try to pass a paremter to my draw function it doesnt work.

```
- (void)drawxy:(CGPoint)startxy //doesnt work
{
    glLineWidth(6.0f);
    ccDrawLine( ccp(0, 0), ccp(150, 150) );
}
-(void)addEnemyAtX:(int)x y:(int)y dir:(int)direction
{
    CCSprite *enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy1.png"];
    enemy.position = ccp(x, y);
    enemy.rotation = [self findDirection:direction];
    [self addChild:enemy];
    [self drawxy:enemy.position];
    [enemies addObject:enemy];
}
```

But when I do this it draws a line for some reason.

```
- (void)drawxy //works
{
    glLineWidth(6.0f);
    ccDrawLine( ccp(0, 0), ccp(150, 150) );
}
-(void)addEnemyAtX:(int)x y:(int)y dir:(int)direction
{
    CCSprite *enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"enemy1.png"];
    enemy.position = ccp(x, y);
    enemy.rotation = [self findDirection:direction];
    [self addChild:enemy];
    [self drawxy];
    [enemies addObject:enemy];
}
```

I know I didnt put the `enemy.position` into the ending of the line point, I was just testing to see if it worked at all which it didnt.
thanks so much for helping.

Comment: for some reason when i change the draw functions name to draw instead of drawxy it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enemy.position=CGPointMake(cp.x, cp.y);
```

And call function

```
[self drawxy:enemy.position];
```